# PHP: How to make this "wrapper" methods properly?

Tags: php, architecture, transactions

I need to do something like this but avoid duplicate calls of `startTransaction` and `stopTransaction`:

```
<?php 
//parent: let's supply transactions!
class MegaParent {

    public $__started;
    //code inside this method must be executed only once - at first call
    public function startTransaction()
    {
        if (!$this->__started) {
            echo "Transaction Started\n";
            $this->__started = true;
        }
    }
    //code inside this method must be executed only once - at last call
    public function stopTransaction()
    {
        if ($this->__started) {
            echo "Transaction Stopped\n";
            $this->__started = null;
        }
    }
}
//Child 1: I do something wrapped in transaction 
class ChildOne extends MegaParent {

    public function doer()
    {
        $this->startTransaction();
        echo "Doing ChildOne\n";
        $this->stopTransaction();
    }
}
//Child 2: I do something in transaction too but I need no nested transactions
class ChildTwo extends ChildOne {

    public function doer()
    {
        $this->startTransaction();
        parent::doer();
        parent::doer();
        echo "Doing ChildTwo\n";
        $this->stopTransaction();
    }
}

(new ChildTwo)->doer();
```

Result:

```
Transaction Started
Doing ChildOne
Transaction Stopped
Transaction Started
Doing ChildOne
Transaction Stopped
Doing ChildTwo
```

How to get result like this:

```
Transaction Started
Doing ChildOne
Doing ChildOne
Doing ChildTwo
Transaction Stopped
```

?

Comment: Sorry, I see the issue.  Use `static` memory for `$__started`.

Comment: I could not solve the problem with static calls but seems I got result using your idea about stack.

Comment: `public static $__started;` will solve your problem with `static::$__started` instead of `$this->$__started` due to the context difference between static and $this.

Comment: @AlexBarker , please show the entire code you could make work properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult when you want to nest the transactions to know how many have started and stopped using just a binary flag.  This code replaces this with a `$transactionLevel` which is incremented and decremented on each call.

```
class MegaParent {
    protected $transactionLevel = 0;
    //code inside this method must be executed only once - at first call
    public function startTransaction()
    {
        if ( $this->transactionLevel == 0 ) {
            echo "Transaction Started\n";
        }
        $this->transactionLevel++;
    }
    //code inside this method must be executed only once - at last call
    public function stopTransaction()
    {
        if ( $this->transactionLevel > 0 )  {
            $this->transactionLevel--;
            if ( $this->transactionLevel == 0 ) {
                echo "Transaction Stopped\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I applied similar method and now the code works as needed